# Transition from Mysql to mysqli for a csv import file that was working

Tags: php, csv, mysqli, mysqlimport

My hoster just depreciated mysql connections in favor of mysqli

this particular script is an example but worked perfectly before I tried to transition to Mysqli. Unfortunately I am 4 years from php programming from another job placement and have not looked at this for quite some time. So please be gentle :-)

I am able to connect to the db but the output looks like this :
Error: INSERT INTO articles (name, reference) VALUES ('','')

I must be doing something wrong with the $data variable but haven't a clue since it worked with a previous version.

I appreciate any assistance

```
<?php  

ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);

function clean($str, $default = '') {
    if (!isset($str)) $str = $default;
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

$host_name  = "some host";
$database   = "some database";
$user_name  = "someusername";
$password   = "some password";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){ echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); } else {echo 'connected to DB<br />';}                       

$lines = $value1 = $value2 = $data = 0;

if ($_FILES["csv"]["size"] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($data[0]) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO articles (name, reference) VALUES ('".clean($data[0])."','".clean($data[1])."')";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) { } else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn); }
           $lines++;
       }
    }    
header('Location: <?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?success=1&lines='.$lines.''); die; 
}
if ( isset($_GET['success']) ) 
{ 
    $success = $_GET['success'];
    $lines = $_GET['lines'];
} else {
    $success = 0;
}
mysqli_close($conn); 
if ($success != 0 ) { 
    echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br>";
    echo "Found a total of ".$lines." records in this csv file.<br />"; 
} 

?> 
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
  Choose your file: <br /> 
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `clean` function, the last line:

```
function clean($str, $default = '') {
    if (!isset($str)) $str = $default;
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
```

As you don't have a `mysql_*` connection, `mysql_real_escape_string` will return `false` which translates to empty strings. You should use the correct function for mysqli but a prepared statement would be even better, then you don't have to clean anything. Apart from regular validation of course.

Note that if you choose to use an escaping function, you will need to send the database connection as a parameter to your function as you need it:

```
function clean($db, $str, $default = '') {
    ...
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $str);
}
```

Comment: well ... i lied ... works for the first csv file and then stops wokring for the second file i try to import

Comment: @sop4 You should try to narrow down the problem and probably ask a new question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

this is working great now ... thanks for the help

```
<?php  

ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);

function clean($link, $str, $default ='') {
    if (!isset($str)) $str = $default;
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $str);
}

$host_name  = "somehost";
$database   = "somedb";
$user_name  = "someusername";
$password   = "somepassword";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {}                       


if (isset($_GET['success'])) { 
    $success = $_GET['success'];
    $lines = $_GET['lines'];
} else {
    $success = 0;
}
if ($success != 0 ) { 
    echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br>";
    echo "Found a total of ".$lines." records in this csv file.<br />"; 
} 

$lines = $value1 = $value2 = $data = 0;

if ($_FILES["csv"]["size"] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        //print_r($data).'<br />';
        if ($data[0]) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `articles` (`name`, `reference`) VALUES ('".clean($connect, $data[0])."','".clean($connect, $data[1])."')";
            //echo $sql.'<br />';
            if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) { } else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connect); }
           $lines++;
       }
    }
header('Location: index.php?success=1&lines='.$lines.'');die;
} 

?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
  Choose your file: <br /> 
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: how do you skip 1st row?